# How to get "real" author of the post on my page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to get the name of the person who published post/comment on my page when they answer "as a page". My attempts to get information via '/pageID_postID?fields=from' results in obtaining the name of the page as this is the information that normal person can see. When I look at the real feed manually via browser, I can see that comment/post was published by a specific person. It is possible to get this information?

Comment: Posts have the `admin_creator` field for that. For comments, I don’t think this info is available.

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting that I can see author when it is an application but not when it is a person. Very likely addition permissions are required